# How can I validate a user for a period of inactivity before authenticating them via login?

Tags: php, validation, symfony, authentication

I am using Symfony2 and want to implement a rule for user login, where I check to see if the user has not logged in for a specific period of time and if so, I lock their account and deny them entry.

So far I have found that the Authentication Events in Symfony2 only consist of Success and Failure. The success event fires after the user has logged in and so their lastLogin field is already updated by that point.

I could create my own lastSystemUse date field on the user, however, that seems unnecessary as there is already a lastLogin field. I would prefer to be able to hook onto an event that fires before the user is authenticated.

Alternatively, is it possible to attach a validator to only the login process. I.e. lastLogin > number of days, but without attaching the validation to the registration process?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom authentication provider: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/security/authentication.html#authentication-providers

Mostly I'm doing that kind of things in commands which are running by cron.
In your case, you can create command which will check all users last login date and block these which were not logged in long time.